# I know the range of functions, but I can't draw a graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

I know the range of functions, but I can't draw a graph. I tried to plot an expression of `5x^2 - 4xy + 2y^2 = 30` in y form. And, the results are as follows:

`y = ±sqrt((240 - 24 x^2)/4) + x (x ≤ 10^(1/2) , x ≥ -10^(1/2)`

I'd like to draw a graph called y, but the range is given as above. I don't know how to set ranges like `x ≤ 10^ (1/2)`, and if you know how to graph more efficiently than this, please advise. The code below is the code I've written so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-10,10,1000000)
c = np.sqrt((240 - 24 * x ** 2) / 4) + x

y = c
y1 = - c

plt.plot(x, y ,'r')
plt.plot(x, y1, 'b')
plt.ylim(-10,10)
plt.xlim(-10,10)
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('i')
plt.show()
```

I thought this would draw a graph, but it won't.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your code and got this error:

```
c = np.sqrt((-240 * 24 * x ** 2) / 4) + x
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
```

I think you're trying to square root negative values

Comment: I'm sorry c = np.sqrt((240 - 24 * x ** 2) / 4) + x

Comment: @acid Please don't put corrections in comments - edit your question instead.

Comment: @acid In that case, try having these lines instead: 

plt.ylim(-100,100) 
plt.xlim(-1,1)

Answer (score 0):

why you limited the y : plt.ylim(-10,10)
the x values are in the range (x ≤ 10^(1/2) , x ≥ -10^(1/2) but not the Y

so you know to delete the :plt.ylim(-10,10)

and you made two plot without using the hold function, this will delete the first plot and show the second
if you want to show them both you must use the hold function

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-10,10,1000000)
c = np.sqrt((240 - 24 * x ** 2) / 4) + x

y = c
y1 = - c

plt.plot(x, y ,'r')
plt.hold(True)
plt.plot(x, y1, 'b')
#plt.ylim(-10,10)
plt.xlim(-10,10)
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('i')
plt.show()
```

Comment: [hold](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hold.html) is always true in pyplot, hence it is deprecated and shouldn't be used.